# Why did Indra not request Krishna to slay the Nivatakavachas?

Tags: mahabharata

Nivatakavachas were powerful demons and even the gods could not slay them. Indra asked Arjuna to slay them after he obtained the celestial weapons. Why did he not ask Krishna to slay them?

Comment: Because Krshna doesn't want to commit genocide. Killing one person is one thing, a whole race another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Indra described Nivatakavachas.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03047.htm

> Boastful of their strength, they are even now planning the destruction of the gods, for, having received a boon, they no longer regard the gods. Those fierce and mighty Danavas live in the nether regions. Even all the celestials together are incapable of fighting with them.

Indra told that Krishna is able to kill them.

> Boastful of their strength, they are even now planning the destruction of the gods, for, having received a boon, they no longer regard the gods. Those fierce and mighty Danavas live in the nether regions. Even all the celestials together are incapable of fighting with them.

Then he told why Krishna should not slay them

> Verily as the illustrious Hari had slain the Nagas in the great lake, he, by sight alone, is capable of slaying those Asuras called the Nivatakavachas, along with their followers. **But the slayer of Madhu should not be urged when the task is insignificant. A mighty mass of energy that he is. It swelleth to increasing proportions, it may consume the whole universe.**